# regex: trying to improve this regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using this regex :

```
[']?[%]?[^"]#([^#]*)#[%]?[']?
```

on this text:

```
insert into table (id,name,age) values ('#var1#' ,#var2#,'#var3#', 3, 'name') where id = '#id#' like "" 
and test=<cfqueryparam value="#id#">
```

For some reason it is catching the comma between `#var2#` and `'#var3#'`
but when I include a `[^,]` it starts doing weird stuff.
Can someone help me with this one.

As I read my regex now, it should find anything that:

- might have a single quote
- might have a percentage
- doesn't have a double quote
- then has a hash (`#`)
- followed by no hash, but all other characters
- then has a hash and followed by a percentage or quote

So why, when I add "no comma" in front does the regex break??

---

Updated Question:

okay, Ill try to explain: a query can look like this:

```
SELECT  e.*, m.man_id, m.man_title, c.cat_id, c.cat_name
FROM    ec_products e, ec_categories c, ec_manufacturers m
WHERE   c.cat_id = e.prod_category AND
        e.prod_manufacturer = m.man_id AND
        e.prod_title LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#attributes.keyword#%"> and
test='#var1#'
ORDER BY e.prod_title
```

Now I want every value between `##`, but not the values that are surrounded by a queryparam tag. So in the example I do want `#var1#` but not `#attributes.keyword#`. Reason for this is that all params in the query that are not surrounded by a tag are unsafe and can cause SQL injection. My current regex is

```
(?!")'?%?#(?!\d)[\w.\(\)]+#%?'?(?!")
```

and it is almost there. It does find the `attributes.keyword` because of the `%`. I just want anything that that has `##` but not surrounded by double quotes, so not `"##"`. This will give me all unsafe params in the sql, like `'#var#'`, or `#aNumber#`, or `'%##'`, or `'%##%'`, or `'##%`, but NOT things like

```
<cfqueryparam value="#variable#">
```

. I hope you understand my intentions?

Comment: You you would want to match ```'#var1#'``` and ```#var2#``` and so on, correct?

Comment: yes, except for the #id# within the <cfqueryparam> tag

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be misunderstanding `[^"]`. It doesn't mean "doesn't have a double quote", but rather means, "one character, which is not a double-quote". Similarly, `[^,]` means "one character, which is not a comma". So your regex:

```
[']?[%]?[^"]#([^#]*)#[%]?[']?
```

will match — for example — this:

```
2#,'#
```

which consists of zero single-quotes, zero percent-signs, one character-which-is-not-a-double-quote (namely `2`), one hash-sign, two characters-which-are-not-hash-signs (namely `,'`), one hash-sign, zero percent-signs, and zero apostrophes. The `,'` is what will be captured by the parentheses.

---

**Update** for updated question:

I don't think that what you describe is possible using *just* a ColdFusion regex, because it would require "lookbehind" (to ensure that something is *not preceded* by a double-quote), which ColdFusion regexes apparently (according to a Google-search) do not support. However:

- [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3047304/978917) gives a way of using Java regexes in ColdFusion. If you use that technique, then you can use the Java regex

  ```
  '?%?(?<!")(?<!"')(?<!"%)(?<!"'%)#(?!\d)[\w.()]+#(?!%?'?")%?'?
  ```

  to ensure that there's no preceding double-quote.
- You never mentioned how you're actually using this regex. Would it work for you to match

  ```
  .'?%?#(?!\d)[\w.()]+#%?'?(?!")
  ```

  (i.e., to match not just the section of interest, but also the preceding character), and then *separately* confirm that the matched substring doesn't start with a double-quote?

I also feel compelled to mention, since it sounds like you're trying to use regex-based pattern-matching to help detect and address points of possible SQL injection, that this is a bad idea; you will never be able to do this perfectly, so if anything, I think it will end up *increasing* your risk of SQL injection (by increasing your reliance on a buggy methodology).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So if you want to catch any text looking like '#var#', #var#, '%#var#%', '#var#%', '%#var#', i reckon I needed a "does not start with a double quote and does not end with a double quotes". Is this: (?!") ?

Comment: @Mattijs: Sorry, but I don't see where double-quotes come into it. `'?%?#[^#]*#%?'?` would match all of your examples, and the only double-quotes they would match are double-quotes between the hash-signs.

Comment: Hi, I do not want this one to be matched: <cfqueryparam value="#id#">
I am doing a replace on all not parameterized variables in the sql. Sometimes they are partially parameterized so then I only need to match those that are not.

Comment: @Mattijs: the problem is that if you have something like `<cfqueryparam value="#id#">, '#var#'`, and you take pains to prevent your regex from matching `#id#`, then your regex will match `#">, '#` rather than the `'#var#'`, because it will try to match the first thing it can. Tell me — will the string between the hash-signs always be identifier-like? That is, will it always consist of letters/numbers/underscores?

Comment: Yes, the coldfusion variable name between the hashes will always be lower or uppercase + numbers and a possible underscore (varIABLE_1)

I must say that this one currently works for me:
(?!")'?%?#[^#]+#%?'?(?!")

Adding the (?!") at the end prevented the regex engine from selecting the #var# in the cfqueryparam. I think it was a bit of a lucky shot. Maybe it is not semantically correct, but it seems to work for all the variations I came up with.
Does (?!") mean : do not end with double quote?

Comment: @Mattijs: `(?!...)` at a given place in the regex means "don't match if, immediately after this point, is `...`. For example, `a(?!b)` matches any `a` that's not followed by a `b`, and `(?!a).` matches any character other than `a`.

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks for the extensive explanation. I did learn from it.

Comment: Hi, I ran into an issue with the expression on the following text: `Exec sp_blable #test#, <cfqueryparam value="#var#">, #id#', 'dssdfsdsdf', 0` with the expression `(?!")'?%?#[^#]+#%?'?(?!")`. If I test this in http://www.regextester.com/ it will select `#">, ` from the <cfqueryparam tag. I do not know why is doing it now, apparently it finds the # and then anything that is not a # [^#] until it finds a new hash. How can I refrain it from doing this?

Comment: @Mattjs: I think the key is to define as narrowly as possible what you *do* want, before you start worrying too much about cutting out things that you *don't* want. From your examples, it looks like you want the stuff between the `#` characters to be a variable-name? Well, `[^#]+` is not a very precise regex for a variable-name; better to write `\w+`, or -- for even better precision -- `(?!\d)\w+`.

Comment: yes, I need all stuff between # # expect when it is used in a cfqueryparam tag. I need to paramatize the non paramatized sql arguments. so `Exec sp_blable #test#, <cfqueryparam value="#var#">, #id#', 'dssdfsdsdf', 0` would eventually become `Exec sp_blable #test#, <cfqueryparam value="#var#">, <cfqueryparam value="#id#">, 'dssdfsdsdf', 0`. I use this one now `(?!")'?%?#(?!\d)\w.+#%?'?(?!")` which also finds `#Attributes,id#`.
What does \d and \w mean?

Comment: @Mattijs: I can't really help you if you don't answer my questions about what you need . . . I asked, "it looks like you want the stuff between the # characters to be a variable-name?", and you replied, "yes, I need all stuff between # #", which doesn't actually answer the question. You mention that your current regex "also finds `#Attributes,id#`", but you don't say if that's good or bad! Re: "What does \d and \w mean?": `\d` matches any digit; `\w` matches any letter, any digit, or an underscore.

Comment: and Ruakh, Thanks for all your effort, much appreciated. I think after this I finally start to understand RegEx. until now it was always a bit of a puzzle to me, difficult to read.

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate it if you would be able to look at my updated question at the top. I am so close to a working solution.
Would be great.

Comment: @Mattijs: I worry that you might not be as close to a working solution as you think; but I've given it a shot. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your new post. I will put into practice and report back. I can access the java layer very easy with CFScript in Coldfusion, so I will give that a try if the standard REreplace() doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Preserving your capture group from the initial regex, here is a revised expression.

```
'?%?(?!")#([^#]+)#%?'?
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `(?!")#` matches any hash sign that does not start with a double-quote — but *no* hash sign starts with a double-quote, so it's equivalent to just `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided this should be correct.

```
'?%?(?!")#[^#]+#%?'?
```

Comment: Thanks.

I did move the (?!") to the back, because in the regex tester it would still select the ID in the cfqueryparam tag, which I want to ignore.
This one (?!")'?%?#[^#]+#%?'?(?!") worked for me.
Many thanks, everyone.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `(?!")#` matches any hash sign that does not start with a double-quote — but *no* hash sign starts with a double-quote, so it's equivalent to just `#`.

Comment: @ruakh, remember, the two characters before it are optional.  It says "maybe a `'`, maybe a %, definitely not a `"`, definitely a `#`."

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Sorry, but I think you're misunderstanding what `(?!...)` means. (I invite you to experiment. Try to find a string that your regex matches but that  `'?%?#[^#]+#%?'?` does not, or vice versa. You won't be able to. The `(?!")` has literally no effect whatsoever when it's followed by `#`.)