# What RegEx engine is used in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

When developing regular expressions it helps not only to know what the limitations are as seen here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ff3.html , but also what the grammar and syntax expected is.  It also helps during testing for apps that can select a Regex engine to test with against a test bed of text or files.

I've seen posted here and there that CF uses Jakarta ORO, http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/ , which is retired late 2010 so that can't be correct or is it still baked into CF9?

If CF10 ships with a different Regex engine as CF9 please also include if known.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046437/regex-find-content-question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**CF9 and CF10 both use Jakarta ORO v2.0.6** - changing it for the existing functions would break backwards compatibility, since other regex engines use different syntax (for both matching and replacement).

However, you can access the [java.util.regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package from CF, which provides access to the version of that engine which your JRE uses, using [createObject/type=java](http://cfdocs.org/createobject-java-or-ejb-object)

If you're not comfortable working with Java classes yourself, I have created a project which wraps the java.util.regex library into a set of handy CFML functions, see [cfregex.net](http://cfregex.net) for more details.

Comment: Yep! The most common benefit is probably lookbehinds, and there's also atomic grouping (which helps improve performance, by preventing backtracking for specific segments), and a few other things. It's also continually updated - for example, JRE 1.7 adds named groups (though not sure if CF is supported on 1.7 yet?)

Comment: There is one benefit to Jakara ORO, which is the `\u`/`\l` and `\U..\E`/`\L..\E` replacement syntax (for convenient uppercasing/lowercasing) - there's no simple equivalent to that with java.util.regex (need to loop through matches/groups doing it manually).

Comment: Henry, I've just replied on the group. _(sorry for delay; had Internet issues)_