# Coldfusion Regex

Tags: regex, arrays, coldfusion

I have a HUGE string `list` (I'll limit the example to one line) with the format:

```
"[First Name] [Last Name] <[email address]>"
```

I ran a regular expression on the string to delimit this into an array.

```
<cfset x = REMatch("<(.*?)>",list) />
```

This works fine, except that it also returns the angular brackets `<>` around the email address

```
x[1] = <[email address]>
```

Just for simplicity sake because the cfdocs are quite regex ambiguous, I wrote this loop to remove the first and last character of each index..

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(x)#" index="y">
    <cfset a = #RemoveChars(x[y], 1, 1)# />
    <cfset a = #left(a,len(a)-1)# />
    <cfset x[y] = a />
</cfloop>
```

This works fine, yay, I have my array now.

However, it's not what I wanted. How can I return the email address WITHOUT the angular brackets included in the first place?

(Please note I also tried `REReplace` and `REFind` only returns the index of the occurrance)

(Also note that there are no `[]` brackets in the string, that's just saying the value inside isn't what I posted here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coldfusion implements a regex flavor (Apache ORO, [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842450/20670)) that doesn't support [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which would be useful in this case.

But we can arrive at an approximation:

```
<cfset x = REMatch("[^<>]+(?=>)",list) />
```

should work as long as all angle brackets occur in unnested, balanced pairs.

**Explanation:**

```
[^<>]+  # Match one or more characters except angle brackets
(?=>)   # Make sure the next character is a closing angle bracket
```

Comment: To be precise, CF's implementation is [Apache ORO](https://jakarta.apache.org/oro/), which is a different implementation to ECMAScript's (though they do both lack lookbehinds).

Comment: That worked perfectly, and thank you for the explanation. I had no idea what lookbehind assertion was before this

Comment: @PeterBoughton: Oh, I didn't know that - [thanks for this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842450/20670)!