# Regex for dd-mmm-yy date format in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to ensure that the user uploaded csv have date in the format dd-mmm-yy (10-Feb-14). I have did my research and I could see that none of the ColdFusion date functions help me to resolve this.

I can use IsValid function with a regular expression validation. I am not good in writing regex. Your help appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a search engine with terms like [date regex "dd-mmm-yy"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=date+regex+%22dd-mmm-yy%22) ?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Peter. I was not aware that we can use javaScript patterns for IsValid. I got it :)

Comment: The isValid function doesn't specifically take JS patterns, but the bulk of regex is the same for most engines (and JS is relatively limited) so they will generally work. [CF's regex is Jakarta ORO v2.0.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842216/what-regex-engine-is-used-in-coldfusion-9/10842450#10842450) which claims to be PCRE/Perl5 compatible (though in reality isn't quite the same).

Comment: Oh and if there's a regex feature you need that CF's functions don't support, Java's one probably does support it. The equivalent to `isValid('regex',string,pattern)` using Java's regex engine would be to use `string.matches(pattern)`

Comment: I am able to do it with:  <br/>

<cfset mydate = "10-Feb-12" /><br/>
<cfset flag = isValid("regular_expression", mydate, "^(d{0}|(31(?!(Feb|feb|Apr|apr|Jun|jun|Sep|sep|Nov|nov)))|((30|29)(?!Feb|feb))|(29(?=Feb|feb(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(29(?=Feb|feb(((0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])[- ](Jan|jan|feb|Feb|mar|Mar|may|May|apr|Apr|jul|Jul|Jun|jun|Aug|aug|Oct|oct|Sep|sep|Nov|nov|dec|Dec)[- ]\d{2}$") /><br/>

Now the issue is 31-Feb-12 is returned as a valid date.

Comment: That looks long-winded - even with month length checks there's probably a simpler one than that (I'd skip the leap year check in the regex and check afterwards for `mydate.startsWith('29-Feb') AND NOT isLeapYear(right(mydate,4))`)

Comment: here is a nice tool to visually see what your regex is actually doing: https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how you can do it with the leap-year check separated...

```
<cffunction name="isCorrectDateFormat" returntype="Boolean" output=false >
    <cfargument name="Input" type="String" />
    <cfscript>
        var Months30 = "Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec";
        var Months31 = "Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec";

        var DatePattern = "(?i)(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9])-(?:#Months30#|Feb)-\d\d|30-(?:#Months30#)-\d\d|31-(?:#Months31#)-\d\d";

        return Arguments.Input.matches(DatePattern)
            AND ( left(Input,6) EQ '29-Feb' IMP isLeapYear('20'&right(Arguments.Input,2)) )
            ;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

It's not perfect (and specifically you might need more advanced logic than prefixing the year with `20`), but it gets you in the ball-park.

Of interest there is the [`IMP` Implication operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html) - where "a IMP b" means "if a is false, return true. If a is true, return b", and thus is a way of doing the leap year check only when it needs to.

The regex itself can be broken down as follows:

```
(?ix) ## i flag enables case-insensitive, x enables comment-mode

    ## match 1-9 or 10-29 days for every month (leap years dealt with separately)
    (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9])-(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Feb)-\d\d
|
    ## or match 30 days for all except Feb
    30-(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d
|
    ## or match 31 days for relevant months
    31-(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)-\d\d
```

For four digit years, the final `\d\d` for each of those can be either `\d\d\d\d` or `\d{4}` or maybe `(?:19\d\d|2[01]\d\d)` depending on specific date ranges involved.

Answer (score 0):

As per Peter's comments, I have modified my code.. I have used a simple regex and then rest is taken care in another validation.

```
<cfset mydate = "31-Apr-12" />
<cfset flag = isValid("regular_expression", Ucase(mydate), "^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\-\d{2}$") />

<cfset aplhaMonths = "APR,JUN,SEP,NOV">
<cfif flag>
<cfif ListGetAt(mydate,1,"-") EQ 31 AND ListFindNocase(aplhaMonths, ListGetAt(mydate,2,"-")) >
<cfset flag = false />
<cfelseif ListGetAt(mydate,1,"-") GT 29 AND ListGetAt(mydate,2,"-") EQ "FEB">
<cfset flag = false />
<cfelseif ListGetAt(mydate,1,"-") EQ 29 AND ListGetAt(mydate,2,"-") EQ "FEB" AND NOT IsLeapYear(mydate)>
<cfset flag = false />
</cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You've gone a bit overboard on the parens in the regex, that first bit can be simplified from `(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))` to `([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`. (Which also avoids `0` and `00` matching.) Also it's worth being aware of the difference between capturing groups `(`..`)` and non-capturing groups `(?:`..`)` - shouldn't apply here but needlessly using capture groups can potentially slow things down and waste memory.

Answer (score 0):

use regex
for date="^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
 for datetime="^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0][0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$"

it will strictly follow YYYY-mm-dd it will not allow yy-mm-dd or yyyy-m-dd oryyyy-mm-d or dd-mm-yyyy.
it will not allow h:m:sor h:mm:s or hh:mm:s it will allow only  (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

Answer (score -1):

If you require particular date format like `((YYYY-MM-DD) or (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss))` only

1. it should not allow 2017-1-2
2. it should not allow 9:9:9 time format too

   f (arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMin neq "" or arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMax neq "") {
                   local.validMinDateFlag = "YES";
                   local.validMaxDateFlag = "YES";

   ```
               if (arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMin neq "")
                   local.validMinDateFlag = isValid ("regex", arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMin, "^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$");

               if (arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMax neq "")
                   local.validMaxDateFlag = isValid ("regex",arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMax, "^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$");

               if (local.validMaxDateFlag eq "NO" or local.validMinDateFlag eq "NO"){
                   if (local.validMinDateFlag eq "NO")
                       local.validMinDateFlag = isValid ("regex",arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMin, "^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0][0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$");

                   if (local.validMaxDateFlag eq "NO")
                       local.validMaxDateFlag = isValid ("regex",arguments.preparedInput.printFileLastModifiedMax, "^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0][0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0][0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$");
               }
   ```