# Regex with or uses second regex when first matches?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I've got a situation were I need to remove parts of a string, and I figured I could use regex for this.

The test case is something similar to

```
LINDA L
LINDSAY GRIFFIN
LINDSAY LIGHTHOUSE
LINDSAY PETERSON
```

and I want to remove the trailing `L\b` from the first or the leading `L.*?\b` from the second and third, which should leave me with this:

```
LINDA
GRIFFIN
LIGHTHOUSE
PETERSON
```

`L\b|L.*?\b` removes the whole first and third line (except the space), which is not what I want. Is there any way to do this with one expression? I assumed that because the first regex matched, it wouldn't move onto the second one.

Thanks everyone, we ended up just using CF conditionals and two replacements instead of one complicated regex.

Comment: what is your expected output? Edit that too in ur ques

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an answer that doesn't overfit to your data set, but just a little note on regex syntax: you don't need the `?` in your second pattern because `*` matches 0 or more times.

Comment: @PeterElliott  The `?` makes it a lazy operator - so the `.*` won't go past the first word boundary.

Comment: duh, you're totally right.  I thought it was equivalent when I tested it, but I just tried it again and they are clearly different.  My bad!

Comment: @Rob, a lookbehind/lookahead might be your answer:  `(?<=LINDA )L\b|^(?!LINDA)L[^\s]*\b` - if the condition you're testing on is what I think it is.  But that might be to specific.  What exactly is it you're looking for? Check this link to see that in action:  http://regexr.com?33b0d

Comment: So just to clarify: 1) each of those is separate strings that you are processing, not one string? 2) If only the person's second *initial* is at the END of the string, get rid; OR 3) if you have the full surname, lose the first name?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: CF doesn't support look behinds.

Comment: I haven't used it, myself but the RegEx Master's (ahem, Peter Boughton's) [custom cfc supposedly does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047304/1147918)

Comment: @AdamCameron Ah, Bummer.

Comment: Sure, using Java's regex processor instead (it's not really anything to do with Peter, per se. He's not *that* good ;-) work do the look-behinds.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: yeah, I've been lobbying Adobe for years to upgrade the regex engine, but they don't seem to care (and it's a feature that doesn't get much buy-in from the CF community either). It's a bit embarrassing.

Comment: Heh heh. I _have_ considered writing/adapting a real regex engine a number of times (the single-direction stuff bugs me, amongst other things), but too many other things to do first. :P

Comment: _"we ended up just using CF conditionals and two replacements instead of one complicated regex."_ - you should post your own solution as the answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is an answer to the question asked, which was how to do it with one expression.

Comment: The accepted solution doesn't need to be the direct/literal answer to a question, but irrespective of that it's still helpful for future readers if you provide the details of what you're actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you want to do:

```
(\bL$)|((?!.*\bL$)^L.*?\b)
```

To explain, `(\bL$)` matches the first pattern: word boundry, then L, then end of line.

`((?!.*\bL$)^L.*?\b)` matches an L at the beginning of a line, followed by the rest of the word (`.*?\b`, as you had, is a reasonable pattern to get to the end of the word).  This: `(?!.*\bL$)` is a negative lookahead, preventing matching if if the pattern following `?!` is matched.  In this case, it will prevent matching if the patterm `\bL$` appears anywhere in the line.

That's what I came up with anyway.  Sure is ugly though.  A much better way to go about it, as you hinted at in the question, would be to use two separate regex patterns, running the second only if the first has not found a match for the line.

Comment: This expression can be simplified to `\bL$|^L\w*(?!.*\bL$)`. Also note that it needs `(?m)` prefixed if being used against a multiline string (rather than multiple single-line strings).

Answer (score 1):

@femtoRgon has almost got it, but leaves some whitespace dangling.  A complete CF solution would be:

```
result = reReplace(string, "(\s*\bL$)|((?!.*\bL$)^L.*?\b\s*)", "", "ONE");
```

Where `string` would be "LINDA L" or "LINDSAY GRIFFIN" etc.

This tests out on all the examples you gave, but it's being pretty literal about the rules you specified.

Comment: As commented on femtoRgon's answer, there's a simpler version of that expression - combined with whitespace removal it'd work like this: 
`reReplace(singleline_string, "\s+L$|^L\w*\s+(?!.*\bL$)", "")` or `reReplace(multiline_string, "(?m)\s+L$|^L\w*\s+(?!.*\bL$)", "", "ALL")`

Comment: @PeterBoughton, yep good call. I should have spotted that, but put myself in a rush that I had no reason to be in ;-)

Answer (score 1):

***Note:** This is assuming you have a single string and want both actions applied if relevant (i.e. the second is not dependent on the first); if that's not what you want you need to clarify the question.*

Doing it with one regex just makes things unnecessarily ugly (and thus less maintainable) - here's a way to do it with two:

```
Input.replaceFirst('\s+L(?=\n)','').replaceAll('(?<=\n)L\w+\s+','')
```

The first expression removes the L (and preceding whitespace) from the first line (and since we're using replaceFirst, only the first line).

The second expression removes all L-words at the start of a line (except the first line, which doesn't have a newline before it).

*(Since in both cases we'll always have `\s+` matching, there's no need for explicit `\b` here; you could use one instead if you didn't want the whitespace removed though.)*

If you prefer to do it with the CFML rereplace function, the equivalent would be:

```
rereplace( rereplace(Input,'\s+L(?=\n)','') , '(\n)L\w+\s+' , '\1' , 'all' )
```

Personally I find the other way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should check conditional regex.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: Not in ColdFusion. CF only supports what Apache Jakarta ORO supported (strange, sad, but true).