# how to get REReplace to be multiline and global

Tags: regex, coldfusion, regex-lookarounds

I get the following errors (they don't show up when I take out the look behind and look ahead in my regex - however it doesn't do multiline and global even when I do (?m) at the beginning of the regex):

```
<!---
Detail: Reason: Sequence (?<...) not recognized.

Message: Malformed regular expression ""(.*)?(https?://)?(?<!@)(www.)?(example.com)(?=/)(.+)?"".

RAW_TRACE    coldfusion.runtime.StringFunc$MalformedRegularExpressionException: Malformed regular expression ""(.*)?(https?://)?(?<!@)(www.)?(example.com)(?=/)(.+)?"".

LINE     54
RAW_TRACE    at ...\file.cfm:54) --->

<!--- initialize a variable --->
<cfset stuff='<p><img alt="" src="/images/dsfsdfsd/all7color.jpg"</p>
  <br><a href="http://example.com/balsdjf.cfm">    
  <p><img alt="" src="/images/efwrer3fedf/all7color.jpg"</p>
  <br><a href="http://example.com/balsdjf.cfm">
'>

<cfscript>    
item=REReplace(stuff, 
               '"(.*)?(https?:\/\/)?(?<!\@)(www\.)?(example.com)(?=\/)\/(.+)?"', 
               '"/5"', 
               'ALL');    
</cfscript>    

<cfoutput>
  #item#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Well, it seems like coldfusion's engine doesn't support lookbehinds (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046437/regex-find-content-question). Also, what do you think multiline does? It wouldn't affect your pattern anyway.

Comment: yeah I tried it with ^ and $ and it still didn't do anything. Oh well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, you're getting your error because you are using a look-behind, and CFML's regular expression engine ([Apache ORO](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/), I'm afraid to say) doesn't support 'em.

If you want to use look-behinds, you can use Java's regex engine instead. I have begun to write up [how to use Java regular expressions via CFML](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part.html) on my blog, if that helps. I haven't discussed the regex pattern syntax yet, but I do cover calling the Java from CFML, and the [pattern syntax is well-documented in the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and linked-to from the articles.

Also @m.buettner is completely correct: the "multi-line" flag "(?m)", btw would have no impact on your situation anyhow, because all it does is change the way `^` and `$` are interpreted, but you have no `^` or `$` in your pattern.

To achieve the "global" flag with a CFML regex replacement operation, you specify `"all"` for the scope argument, as you already have.

I think this answers your question, but I think what/why you're asking needs a rethink perhaps. Other than the look-behind not being supported, what's actually not working with what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you Adam!!!!! I actually got around using the look behinds and look aheads by using [^] but i'll play with the Java regular expressions like you suggested.