# Regular expression to find position of the last alpha character that is followed by a space?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 10. I rarely need to use regular expression and really need some help.

I have some lengthy content (up to 8,000 characters) and want to create a teaser. After a certain length (which I will define elsewhere), I want to find the last alpha character that is followed by a space. I will remove everything after that character.  I will then add the ellipsis (...)

```
MyString = "The lazy brown fox is not a dog."
```

In this case, I would delete everything after the "a" that precedes "dog".

```
MyString = "There are 123 boxes on up the hill, says that 612 guy."
```

In this case, I would delete everything after the "that" that precedes "612 ".

```
MyString = "I fell down the stairs on June 30th, 1962."
```

In this case, I would delete everything after the "June" that precedes "30th".

What regular expression would I use to find the position of the last alpha [a-Z] character that is followed by a space?

```
MyReg = "";
LastPosition = reFindNoCase(MyReg, MyString);
```

Comment: not sure about ColdFusion syntax, but a regex of the form `/^.*([a-zA-Z]) /` should do it. The `.*` is greedy, so it's going to eat as much as it can. (Note that there is a space between the ']' and '/'). The character will be in the capture group.

Comment: **precedes** - (verb) 1. *Come before (something) in time.* 2. *Come before in order or position: "read the chapters that precede the recipes".* Everything after the "a" that precedes "dog" would be a single space. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, in the first example, everything after the "a" that precedes "dog" would be a single space. I want to know the position of that single space. Is there a regular expression that will return that position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about REFindNoCase, but I think you can try with REReplaceNoCase. I hope that CF can take back references like most regex engines do:

```
REReplaceNoCase(MyString, "(.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)\s.*", "$1", ALL);
```

---

**EDIT:** for the backreference, it appears that you use the backslash instead of the dollar sign:

```
REReplaceNoCase(MyString, "(.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)\s.*", "\1", ALL);
```

---

And if it goes well, you should have something like [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/cB6kC6).

`.*` matches anything besides a newline character, `\b` matches word boundaries, `[a-zA-Z]+` are for alphabet characters and `\s` is for the space just after it.

The greediness of the first `.*`'s is being exploited here to capture as much as possible until you get the last word followed by a space.

And I guess you can add the ellpses after the `$1` like so:

```
REReplaceNoCase(MyString, "(.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)\s.*", "\1 (...)", ALL)
```

---

If you only want to use `REFind()`, you could maybe use this:

```
REFindNoCase("[A-Za-z](?:\s\d+|\w+,)*\s[^\s]+\.$", MyString);
```

Note that I haven't tested this against other possible scenarios, but I tried a few which don't work with the above but with this one:

```
REFindNoCase("[A-Za-z](?:\s\d+|\s?\w+[,.-]+)*\s[^\s]+[.\s]*$", MyString);
```

And those are the few test subjects: [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/sH9lB7).

`REFind` will give you the position of the last alpha character. You can add 1 to get the position of the space in the original string.

Comment: deleted my answer in favor of yours :)

Comment: +1 - ColdFusion can handle back references but I think the syntax is slightly different. [Using backreferences](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=regexp_10.html) `\1` instead of `$1`

Comment: *Re: I hope that CF can take back references like most regex engines do:* Yep. It [uses Apache ORO internally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046437/regex-find-content-question/3047304#3047304). So backreferences are expressed as "\1" rather than "$1". (Edit: @Miguel-F Uh-oh, vulcan mind meld alert ;-)

Comment: @Miguel-F Thanks! Edited the answer. I've seen most engines turn towards `$1` from `\1` though and guessed they were following the latest trend.

Comment: @Leigh - ha! I just edited my comment to include the different notation and see that you added it as well.

Comment: Actually, it seems that you are grabbing and editing the string. That's not the answer that I was looking for. I am looking for how to find the position of the last character.  I am hoping to to return an integer.

Comment: @EvikJames But you mention you "would delete everything after the "a" that precedes "dog". The replace regex does that for you without having to find the position of the last character. Isn't that your ultimate goal?

Comment: Yes, that is partially my ultimate goal. But that is not what I was looking for right now. That's not what I asked for. I really want a regex that will find the position of the last alpha character is followed by a space. Is that possible with a regex?

Comment: @EvikJames - then just use `REFind()` or `REFindNoCase()` instead of `REReplaceNoCase()` (and you don't need the third parameter replacement string). Here is the [documentation for REFind](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e9a.html) and [documentation for REFindNoCase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e99.html) (I really don't know what the difference is between the two when you are using a regular expression to include/exclude case anyway.)

Comment: @EvikJames It isn't as simple with `REFind()`, and you can get a lot of exceptions. See if my updated answer fits you.

Comment: Heh, I'm a little curious about the thought processes behind that expression there. :S
Whilst refind isn't as simple as rematch, unless I'm being incredibly dense it's still only `Result = refind('.*[a-zA-Z] ',MyString,0,true); Result.Len[1];` Of course, walking backwards through the string is going to be more efficient than both (even though it's more lines of CFML).

Comment: @PeterBoughton I was explicitly using REFind to do this. Note that it REReplace could have been used and then find the length of the result string to get the position of the last character.

Comment: You were using refind with a confusingly complex pattern, and also matching any whitespace (not just space). Yes, checking the length of the result of `rereplace('(.*[a-zA-Z] ).*',input,'\1','one')` would work, but has no benefit over rematch.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with long strings, a regex would need to scan the whole string to get to the end, and it's likely more efficient to instead start at the end and work backwards.

Like this:

```
LastPos = len(String);

while( LastPos > 1 )
{
    LastPos = String.lastIndexOf(' ',LastPos-1);

    if ( mid(String,LastPos,1).matches('[a-zA-Z]') )
        break;

}

NewString = left(String,LastPos);
```

The idea is to keep stepping backwards finding spaces, and break the loop when the previous character is a letter (or the start of the string is reached).

If you really want a regex solution, just do:

```
NewString = rematch('.*[a-zA-Z] ',MyString)[1];
```

To get the position, you do `len(NewString)`.

<sub>(If newlines are involved, you'd need to put `(?s)` at the start of the expression so that the dot matches them.)</sub>